# Mesh Not Following Curve

Tags: bezier-curves

I've been following [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lo_FxdSe_F8) and managed to do the hair correctly for the front part of my head, but for some reason I'm unable to get the mesh to properly follow the curve for the hair mesh meant to come down the side of the head.

The Mean Tilt for my curve is the same as the curve for my front-facing hair curve, and yes, the origin of both the curve and mesh are at the same spot.

The curve is set to `-Z` because I want the mesh to be upright when I'm editing it (see image), but this makes the mesh in object mode not curve downward along the curve to look like a hair. The mesh follows the curve perfectly if set to `-Y`, but then I have to work with my view turned on the side.

Its a bit confusing to explain, but basically, I want the mesh to be upright when I'm editing it, but I want it to follow the curve correctly from the side while it is in object mode (and downward vertically so it looks like hair) - I can't seem to have both.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i may be misinterpreting the question, but it seems to me that if you want the mesh to deform the the curve, you need to add some loop cuts going down, a mesh can only deform along a loop

Comment: fuck me, how did i not fucking realize that... such a simple solution. Thanks! And I'm surprised you were able to follow along with all that.